# getting exception No such payment_intent while implementing strip in android

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments, strip

[image]
PaymentResultCallback Error  Request-id: req_MGyLTQyOn3I8g6 com.stripe.android.exception.InvalidRequestException: No such payment_intent:'pi_1IX00QCDJIQbpq2SeG5K0R84'

Comment: Check API / Server key. and check https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#android

Answer (score 0):

Change publishable key when you initialize Stripe variable (Use this key only for testing when you make your app live use live key)

In my case

```
stripe = new Stripe(getApplicationContext(), Objects.requireNonNull("pk_test_9OsFgGsbGyohk6dzw7bbFlLP00100jL2UE"));
```

https://stripe.com/docs/keys

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right set of publishable and secret key for the right environment.